# Jupyter Notebook doesn't print until execution is done

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook to download data and write to a zip in chunks as below:

```
def _download(url, dest_path):
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    req.raise_for_status()

    completed = 0
    size = len(req.content)
    for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=2 ** 20):
      fd.write(chunk)
      completed += 2 ** 20
      print(f"Downloading: {round(completed/size*100, 1)}%")
      sys.stdout.flush()

def get_data():

    ratings_url = ("http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/" "~cziegler/BX/BX-CSV-Dump.zip")

    if not os.path.exists("data"):
        os.makedirs("data")

        _download(ratings_url, "data/data.zip")
```

The issue is when I try to print the progress. It will not print anything until the execution is done. I have tried flushing to no avail.

I have also tried a simple for loop with time.sleep and it prints i every 2 seconds as expected.

```
import time
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Everything is printed out at once when execution terminates:

[image: Everything printed at once]

Comment: _I have tried flushing to no avail_ Show us.

Comment: Is the output of this program going to a plain terminal?  Or are you redirecting to a file?  Show us exactly how this program is executed.

Comment: I execute the code in jupyter notebook and the output prints in the notebook itself

Comment: Did you try `print(stuff, flush=True)`?

Comment: @SimonLundberg, Yes, it still only prints everything when execution terminates

Comment: I'm guessing this is caused by some other area of the program that you haven't shown us.  As an experiment, try altering the `_download()` function, and replace the `for chunk` loop with the exact loop you showed in the second example, and see what happens.